# JCache "page" group caches all page?

Tags: caching, joomla, joomla2.5

I thought that every module and component is loaded from different files from cache(tmp folder?), into one page and if one module is set to "no caching" then this module is loaded in usual manner (not cached, updated on everypage load). This looks logical for me, as there are separate caches for modules. But when I make one module on page which is set to "no caching" and I change for example it's view (default.php in tmpl folder), the content of page remains same. If I clear the "page" group of cache, then the page is shown with new module's view. I dont really understand if page is loaded from "page" cache, why there are caches for modules when ? What i'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has several levels of cache.  The behaviour you are expecting comes from Joomla standard cache, which is enabled in the site's Global Configuration, and the modules individual settings. Your expectations are correct.

The behaviour you are experiencing comes from the system plugin Cache, which you can disable easily in the Extensions/Plugin page, and still take advantage of the other cache.